# Data Binding Issue: How do I get the Binding value to work both ways?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working on a MVVM WPF application and I have a `CheckBox` which I am trying to work on. What I want is for the value to be binding to a model property (which I have done). However, when I click it in a debugging session it never actually changes my `IsChecked` property to `true` from its default `false`. Please see code below:

#### Model

```
public class MyModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private bool _isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set
            {
                if (_isChecked == value)
                    return;
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

#### View

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="51" Width="667" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="45">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Command="{Binding CheckBoxClickCommand}"  Content="We're in the matrix" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,200,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

#### ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyModel _myModel = new MyModel();
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> UrlsList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
    public ICommand CheckBoxClickCommand { get; private set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
      CheckBoxClickCommand = new RelayCommand(CheckBoxOnClick);
    }
    public void CheckBoxOnClick()
        {
            var newList = new List<MyModel>();
            if (_myModel.IsChecked)
            {
                foreach (var url in UrlsList)
                {
                    if (!url.ExistsInDb)
                        newList.Add(url);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

When I debug and get to the if statement in `CheckBoxClickCommand` it obviously goes to the model to get the property value, but it does not change from the default `false` to `true`. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!.

Comment: Are you trying to bind to the `IsChecked` property of the model? Then you need to expose the model as public property.

Comment: I see what you mean, I just changed the DataContext to my Model and I can see the code executes the setter. So my next question is can I have two data sources of data in one view? Or please suggest a better alternative. Thanks :)

Comment: No. A view only has one DataContext. Did you see my answer? It tells you what to do: Add a Model property to the view model and add the name of this property to the binding path in the XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the model's property:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Model.IsChecked}" ...>
```

For this to work, the model has to be returned from a *public property* of the view model:

```
private MyModel _myModel = new MyModel();
public MyModel Model { get { return _myModel; }}
```

Comment: This works thanks so much!!! Is there a better way to do this by the way? Just wondering.

Comment: This way is perfectly fine.

Comment: @steve: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.